# Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error: Invalid or Corrupt Jar file When adding certificate to exe file

Tags: java, windows, exe, digital-certificate, signtool

I am creating a ***jar*** file using netbeans. Then I create ***exe*** of this jar file using [lanch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). When I run this ***exe*** file on my computer it's run fine But When I run this ***exe*** on some other computer it gives me warning

**The publisher could not be verified. Are you want to run this software**

When click on Run the exe file runs fine.

[image]

I remove that warning by adding certificate to my exe file using **signtool.exe** which comes with **windows sdk**. and it successfully added certificate to my **exe file**.

But now when I run my exe file it gives me error

"***Java Virtual Machine Launcher 
Error: Invalid or Corrupt Jar file***"

[image]

Plz Help me.

Thanks.